# using data from one query in another

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, and have probably got my self into an XY loop.

Essentially I have a query that is pulling ~1.5 million rows of data from MS SQL server and loading it into Power BI. This data contains identifiers and dates that I then want to use within a query of a DB2 database.

What I think I need to do is to is load this into a table/list/parameter that is then the beginning of my second query where I then start making joins to my DB2 database. I'd then be looking to merge the SQL query and DB2 query within Power BI with the Merge Queries function

MS SQL Query results

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | Date   | SQLA | SQLB | SQLC | SQLD | SQLE |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1/1/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 1  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 2  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 2  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to use to start my DB2 query

```
---------------
| ID | Date   |
---------------
| 1  | 1/1/19 |
| 1  | 1/2/19 |
| 2  | 1/2/19 |
| 2  | 1/2/19 |
---------------
```

What I'd like my DB2 Query to look like

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | Date   | DB2A | DB2B | DB2C | DB2D | DB2E |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1/1/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 1  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 2  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
| 2  | 1/2/19 | x    | x    | x    | x    | x    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it? I've tried creating lists and parameters but that is where I think I've been getting into the situation of trying to resolve errors and going round in circles for something that may not actually be the correct solution.

If this isn't possible is there I way I can appending columns onto the original query from a second data source?

Comment: Import both queries from both data sources into Power BI and then merge them.

Comment: if I don't limit it to the IDs and Dates the DB2 query would probably be ~50 billion rows

Comment: Then Power BI is not the right tool for this task. You must transfer these 1.5 million rows from MSSQL to the DB2 database, join then there and only after that go to Power BI. Some tool must filter these 50 billion rows and in your case the most efficient solution is to do this is the source database to avoid data movement.